read only mode in vs code reset back to writable mode every time i reload the window
why every time I set a file as a read-only mode in vs code
reset Back to writable mode after I reload vs code window (using + command shift + P ==> file: set active editor read-only in session) or after I restart vs code
how can I make it permanent?
in pycharm usually stays on read-only mode after I restart pycharm

The keywords in the commands you're using to set read-only mode is "in session". The session being from the time that you open that VS Code instance/window to when it closes. When you open a new VS Code instance/window, that's a new session. If you want to set this stuff permanently, use the files.readonlyInclude setting and optional related settings. See also the globbing reference.

thx again starball you saved me twice in one day lol

one more question is there a fast way to toggle read-only mode globally on/off like the way we do in session through command palette

@Zorro not that I know of. you can add * to your files.readonlyInclude but that's still a little manual.

I found this extension called Reader Mode the good news is that it's semi-permanent ( only in the open tab once you close the tab you lose the read mode) but the bad news is you still have to use the command palette to toggle it ( no icon on status bar to toggle it) and you don't have to go through the file.readonlyinclude unless you want to make it fully permanent
